# How to add three foreign key for same child table with three master tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, database, master-detail

Here I have four tables in my database named `test_center`. Those are:

1. `test_user` --> PK = `u_id`
2. `test_metadata` --> PK = `test_id`
3. `student_detail` --> PK = `Student_id`
4. `test_records` --> PK = `test_record_id` (Child table)

Table 4 is child table and 1, 2, 3 are masters.
I am trying for `test_records` table to have three foreign keys from each of these master tables, but it is showing some errors as follows. (I am using MySQL Workbench 5.0 and MySQL server)

> ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'test_center.#sql-aa4_12' (errno: 121)

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `test_center`.`test_records` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Student_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Student_id` )
  REFERENCES `test_center`.`student_detail` (`Student_id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `test_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`test_id` )
  REFERENCES `test_center`.`test_metadata` (`test_id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `u_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`u_id` )
  REFERENCES `test_center`.`test_user` (`u_id` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

> ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
>   ERROR 1046: No database selected

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_records` (
  `test_record_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Result` float NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Student_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`enter code here`
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_record_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: execute `use mydb;` first to select mydb as the default db.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is unable to identify the database. You need to tell MySQL which database to use:

```
USE database_name;
```

before you create a table.In case the database does not exist, you need to create it as:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

followed by

```
 USE database_name;
```